# Como fazer para estender um método global em testes com uso de globalThis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Estou fazendo um [exercício de Node.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJYsN4DcLQQ&list=PLz_YTBuxtxt6_Zf1h-qzNsvVt46H8ziKh&index=6), porém a versão que estou trabalhando é mais nova, e passou a adotar o `globalThis` na instância  `global`.

```
import { SetupServer } from "./server";
import supertest from "supertest";

beforeAll(()=>{
   const server = new SetupServer();
   server.init();
   //quero colocar esse testRequest como sendo um método global do node.
   global.testRequest = supertest(server.getApp());
});
```

Então na versão antiga do node, conforme é apresentado pelo [exercício](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJYsN4DcLQQ&list=PLz_YTBuxtxt6_Zf1h-qzNsvVt46H8ziKh&index=6), eu teria que sobrescrever o `global` do node com o arquivo `test/globals.d.ts` com essa interface:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    testRequest: import('supertest').SuperTest<import('supertest').Test>;
  }
}
```

Mas o `global` não possui mais uma classe `Global` dentro da versão atual do `node` v10.19.0, agora ele aponta o global para um tipo `globalThis`:

```
declare var global: typeof globalThis;
```

A dúvida que surge é como eu teria que reescrever `test/globals.d.ts` para que o `global.testRequest = ...` funcione de maneira global, podendo ser um método global da chamada do `supertest`. Agora que o global passou a ter a nova implementação `globalThis`.

Este é o formato atual do Typescript do `node` que estou utilizando: `globals.d.ts`:

```
// Declare "static" methods in Error
interface ErrorConstructor {
    /** Create .stack property on a target object */
    captureStackTrace(targetObject: object, constructorOpt?: Function): void;

    /**
     * Optional override for formatting stack traces
     *
     * @see https://v8.dev/docs/stack-trace-api#customizing-stack-traces
     */
    prepareStackTrace?: ((err: Error, stackTraces: NodeJS.CallSite[]) => any) | undefined;

    stackTraceLimit: number;
}

// Node.js ESNEXT support
interface String {
    /** Removes whitespace from the left end of a string. */
    trimLeft(): string;
    /** Removes whitespace from the right end of a string. */
    trimRight(): string;

    /** Returns a copy with leading whitespace removed. */
    trimStart(): string;
    /** Returns a copy with trailing whitespace removed. */
    trimEnd(): string;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------*
 *                                               *
 *                   GLOBAL                      *
 *                                               *
 ------------------------------------------------*/

// For backwards compability
interface NodeRequire extends NodeJS.Require { }
interface RequireResolve extends NodeJS.RequireResolve { }
interface NodeModule extends NodeJS.Module { }

declare var process: NodeJS.Process;
declare var console: Console;

declare var __filename: string;
declare var __dirname: string;

declare var require: NodeRequire;
declare var module: NodeModule;

// Same as module.exports
declare var exports: any;

/**
 * Only available if `--expose-gc` is passed to the process.
 */
declare var gc: undefined | (() => void);

//#region borrowed
// from https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/38da7c600c83e7b31193a62495239a0fe478cb67/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts#L633 until moved to separate lib
/** A controller object that allows you to abort one or more DOM requests as and when desired. */
interface AbortController {
    /**
     * Returns the AbortSignal object associated with this object.
     */

    readonly signal: AbortSignal;
    /**
     * Invoking this method will set this object's AbortSignal's aborted flag and signal to any observers that the associated activity is to be aborted.
     */
    abort(): void;
}

/** A signal object that allows you to communicate with a DOM request (such as a Fetch) and abort it if required via an AbortController object. */
interface AbortSignal {
    /**
     * Returns true if this AbortSignal's AbortController has signaled to abort, and false otherwise.
     */
    readonly aborted: boolean;
}

declare var AbortController: {
    prototype: AbortController;
    new(): AbortController;
};

declare var AbortSignal: {
    prototype: AbortSignal;
    new(): AbortSignal;
    // TODO: Add abort() static
};
//#endregion borrowed

/*----------------------------------------------*
*                                               *
*               GLOBAL INTERFACES               *
*                                               *
*-----------------------------------------------*/
declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface CallSite {
        /**
         * Value of "this"
         */
        getThis(): unknown;

        /**
         * Type of "this" as a string.
         * This is the name of the function stored in the constructor field of
         * "this", if available.  Otherwise the object's [[Class]] internal
         * property.
         */
        getTypeName(): string | null;

        /**
         * Current function
         */
        getFunction(): Function | undefined;

        /**
         * Name of the current function, typically its name property.
         * If a name property is not available an attempt will be made to try
         * to infer a name from the function's context.
         */
        getFunctionName(): string | null;

        /**
         * Name of the property [of "this" or one of its prototypes] that holds
         * the current function
         */
        getMethodName(): string | null;

        /**
         * Name of the script [if this function was defined in a script]
         */
        getFileName(): string | null;

        /**
         * Current line number [if this function was defined in a script]
         */
        getLineNumber(): number | null;

        /**
         * Current column number [if this function was defined in a script]
         */
        getColumnNumber(): number | null;

        /**
         * A call site object representing the location where eval was called
         * [if this function was created using a call to eval]
         */
        getEvalOrigin(): string | undefined;

        /**
         * Is this a toplevel invocation, that is, is "this" the global object?
         */
        isToplevel(): boolean;

        /**
         * Does this call take place in code defined by a call to eval?
         */
        isEval(): boolean;

        /**
         * Is this call in native V8 code?
         */
        isNative(): boolean;

        /**
         * Is this a constructor call?
         */
        isConstructor(): boolean;
    }

    interface ErrnoException extends Error {
        errno?: number | undefined;
        code?: string | undefined;
        path?: string | undefined;
        syscall?: string | undefined;
        stack?: string | undefined;
    }

    interface ReadableStream extends EventEmitter {
        readable: boolean;
        read(size?: number): string | Buffer;
        setEncoding(encoding: BufferEncoding): this;
        pause(): this;
        resume(): this;
        isPaused(): boolean;
        pipe<T extends WritableStream>(destination: T, options?: { end?: boolean | undefined; }): T;
        unpipe(destination?: WritableStream): this;
        unshift(chunk: string | Uint8Array, encoding?: BufferEncoding): void;
        wrap(oldStream: ReadableStream): this;
        [Symbol.asyncIterator](): AsyncIterableIterator<string | Buffer>;
    }

    interface WritableStream extends EventEmitter {
        writable: boolean;
        write(buffer: Uint8Array | string, cb?: (err?: Error | null) => void): boolean;
        write(str: string, encoding?: BufferEncoding, cb?: (err?: Error | null) => void): boolean;
        end(cb?: () => void): void;
        end(data: string | Uint8Array, cb?: () => void): void;
        end(str: string, encoding?: BufferEncoding, cb?: () => void): void;
    }

    interface ReadWriteStream extends ReadableStream, WritableStream { }

    interface RefCounted {
        ref(): this;
        unref(): this;
    }

    type TypedArray =
        | Uint8Array
        | Uint8ClampedArray
        | Uint16Array
        | Uint32Array
        | Int8Array
        | Int16Array
        | Int32Array
        | BigUint64Array
        | BigInt64Array
        | Float32Array
        | Float64Array;
    type ArrayBufferView = TypedArray | DataView;

    interface Require {
        (id: string): any;
        resolve: RequireResolve;
        cache: Dict<NodeModule>;
        /**
         * @deprecated
         */
        extensions: RequireExtensions;
        main: Module | undefined;
    }

    interface RequireResolve {
        (id: string, options?: { paths?: string[] | undefined; }): string;
        paths(request: string): string[] | null;
    }

    interface RequireExtensions extends Dict<(m: Module, filename: string) => any> {
        '.js': (m: Module, filename: string) => any;
        '.json': (m: Module, filename: string) => any;
        '.node': (m: Module, filename: string) => any;
    }
    interface Module {
        /**
         * `true` if the module is running during the Node.js preload
         */
        isPreloading: boolean;
        exports: any;
        require: Require;
        id: string;
        filename: string;
        loaded: boolean;
        /** @deprecated since 14.6.0 Please use `require.main` and `module.children` instead. */
        parent: Module | null | undefined;
        children: Module[];
        /**
         * @since 11.14.0
         *
         * The directory name of the module. This is usually the same as the path.dirname() of the module.id.
         */
        path: string;
        paths: string[];
    }

    interface Dict<T> {
        [key: string]: T | undefined;
    }

    interface ReadOnlyDict<T> {
        readonly [key: string]: T | undefined;
    }
}
```

Há um dizer que no futuro isso seria [utilizado desta maneira](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4/#type-checking-for-globalthis), mas o futuro já chegou:

```
globalThis.testRequest = import('supertest').SuperTest<import('supertest').Test>;
```

E o `global.testRequest` já seria acessível assim, porém o vscode ainda acusa de que o método não existe no global.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem. `global.testRequest` não funciona porque não existe `Global` ai voce queria alterar o tipo de `globalThis`?

Comment: Não, a propriedade global não possui mais propriedades, estas propriedades são indiretas, pois estão no globalThis. Então o acesso é pelo global, mas a atribuição é no globalThis, [veja esse comentário](https://www.ti-enxame.com/pt/node.js/estendendo-o-objeto-global-typescript-no-node.js/822341525/)

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver o problema declarando um `namespace globalThis` e uma `var` com a assinatura desejada, dessa forma:

```
declare namespace globalThis {
  declare var testRequest: import('supertest').SuperTest<
    import('supertest').Test
  >
}
```

Comment: Essa maneira está com problemas na sintaxe e de conflito [veja qui](https://im.ge/i/error.U6Jwc).

Comment: você precisa colocar isso em um arquivo com a extensão `.d.ts`, em um arquivo `.ts` normal ele vai reclamar.

Comment: tentei resolver desta maneira, mas para mim um outro erro é gerado: Declaration name conflicts with built-in global identifier 'globalThis'.ts(2397)

Answer (score -1):

Olá, Gabriel.

Eu consegui suprimir o erro com o seguinte código em globals.d.conf (node versão 16.14.0):

```js
declare global {
  var testRequest: import('supertest').SuperTest<import('supertest').Test>;
}

export {};
```